# Is there a way to render a string dust template without compiling it first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dust.js

Is it possible to do something like this with dustjs? As oppose to compiling a template, then referring to it in the render method.

```
>    
> var dust = require('dustjs-linkedin');
>
> dust.stringRender("Hello {name}, how are you?", { name: "Joe" }, function(err, res) {
>   console.log(res);
> });
'Hello Joe, how are you?'
>
```

I know that stringRender is a fictitious method; its just for clarity.

Comment: What's wrong with compiling it and immediately invoking?

Comment: Because it would be more convenient when prototyping template functionality to be able to render small strings as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this yourself with just a couple lines of code-- this is Javascript, after all.

```
 function stringRender(source, context, callback) {
    var tmpl = dust.loadSource(dust.compile(source));
    return dust.render(tmpl, context, callback);
 }
```

However, we recognize this is a typical case and so you can use `dust.renderSource` exactly as you used your function `stringRender` above. (The code above is basically the code of `dust.renderSource`.)

```
dust.renderSource("Hello {name}!", { name: "Jim" }, function(err, data) {
  ...
});
```

Or as a stream:

```
dust.renderSource("Hello {name}!", { name: "Jim" }).pipe(...)
```

However, you **should not use this** in production because compilation is the slowest part of the Dust template lifecycle. In production, you should always precompile and cache your templates.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but https://jsfiddle.net/7jfzpgby/ to play

```
if (!dust.stringRender)
{
  dust.stringRender = function (template, data, cb)
  {
    var compiled = dust.compile(template);
    var template = dust.loadSource(compiled);
    dust.render(template, data, cb);
  };
}

dust.stringRender("Hello {name}, how are you?", { name: "Joe" }, function (error, output) {
  console.info(output);
})
```